# Coluna fixa de um JTable em um JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Como faço para deixar uma coluna de um JTable fixa (sem scroll) dentro de um JScrollPane?

Quero deixar a primeira coluna de uma tabela fixa, a barra de rolagem só irá rolar da segunda coluna em diante, a primeira deve sempre ficar visível.

Até consegui fazer porém tenho que dividir a tabela em duas...

Comment: Não sei se isso é de fato possível. Me parece que a sua solução de dividir a tabela em duas é a melhor.

Comment: @Victor Pelo jeito não dá pra escapar de criar duas `JTable`, mas parece ser possível usar **um único `TableModel`** e fazer cada tabela (cabeçalho e "resto") usar só uma parte desse modelo.

Answer (score 3):

O que você está procurando é uma [*row header*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setRowHeader%28javax.swing.JViewport%29) (cabeçalho de linha - compare com *column header*, usado quando você quer uma **linha** fixa no topo). Há uma [pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1434933/520779) no StackOverflow em inglês, mas as respostas não contém muitas informações, somente [dois](http://www.chka.de/swing/table/row-headers/JTable.html) [links](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/).

Dei uma olhada rápida nos dois, e ambos separam a `JTable` em duas... Entretanto, o primeiro link permite usar **um único** `TableModel` para ambas as tabelas - que é o que realmente importa, certo?

Veja o link para a solução completa. Exemplo de uso (simplificado):

```java
TableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(0,10); // Substitua com seu TableModel particular

// Criando o modelo de coluna para a tabela "normal" (coluna 1 em diante)
TableColumnModel columns = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
for (int count = data.getColumnCount(), i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    TableColumn c = new TableColumn(i);
    c.setHeaderValue(data.getColumnName(i));
    columns.addColumn(c);
}

// Criando o modelo de coluna para o cabeçalho (coluna 0; se quiser pode fixar mais colunas)
TableColumnModel headerColumns = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
TableColumn h = new TableColumn(0);
h.setHeaderValue(data.getColumnName(0));
headerColumns.add(h);

// Criando as tabelas
JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
JTable rowHeader = new JTable(data, headerColumns);

// RowHeaderRendered é uma classe externa, que pode ser baixada no link acima
rowHeader.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new RowHeaderRenderer());

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);
```

Comment: foi mais ou menos isso que eu fiz, na verdade especializei um JScrollPane, vou postar a minha solução para quem quiser ver. Talvez quando tiver mais tempo eu tente de outra maneira

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução até então:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JFixedColScrollPane extends JScrollPane {

  private JTable fixedTable;
  private JTable mainTable;

  public JFixedColScrollPane( JTable fxTable, JTable mnTable ) throws Exception {
    super( mnTable );
    this.fixedTable = fxTable;
    this.mainTable = mnTable;

    fixedTable.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );
    mainTable.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

    setRowHeaderView( fixedTable );

    ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
      public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent e ) {
        JTable tabelaSelecionada = (e.getSource() == fixedTable.getSelectionModel()) ? fixedTable : mainTable;
        JTable tabelaASelecionar = (tabelaSelecionada == fixedTable) ? mainTable : fixedTable;
        tabelaASelecionar.getSelectionModel().removeListSelectionListener( this );
        tabelaASelecionar.clearSelection();
        int linha = tabelaSelecionada.getSelectedRow();
        if ( linha >= 0 ) {
          tabelaASelecionar.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval( linha, linha );
          if ( tabelaSelecionada == fixedTable ) {
            Rectangle rectangle = tabelaASelecionar.getCellRect( linha, 0, false );
            rectangle.width = tabelaASelecionar.getWidth();
            tabelaASelecionar.scrollRectToVisible( rectangle );
          }
        }
        tabelaASelecionar.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( this );
      }
    };

    this.fixedTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( listSelectionListener );
    this.mainTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( listSelectionListener );

    final JTableHeader fixedTableHeader = this.fixedTable.getTableHeader();
    setCorner( ScrollPaneConstants.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, fixedTableHeader );

    fixedTable.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentResized( ComponentEvent e ) {
        fixedTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize( new Dimension( fixedTable.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), 50 ) );
      }
    } );
  }

  public JTable getFixedTable() throws Exception {
    return fixedTable;
  }

  public JTable getMainTable() throws Exception {
    return mainTable;
  }
}
```

para utilizar:

```
new JFixedColScrollPane( tabelaFixa, tabelaMovel );
```